# What is this aircraft shown in 'Operation Buffalo' (TV show)?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Its registration appears to be VH-AES but a search of the Australian database shows it as being a DC-3??

[image: Front View - with Gear]

[image: Unloading Ramp]

[image: Screenshot from TV Series: Operation Buffalo]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the name of the movie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like a [Bristol Type 170 Freighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_Freighter): (All images are from the linked Wikipedia article).

The more I look at the images you posted the more it looks like a CGI than an actual aircraft.

Regarding the registration:

- To me it looks more like VH-AEN
- The images you posted seem like they are from a movie. Movies often use fake registration numbers.
- Next time it might be beneficial to mention the name of the movie.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's absolutely a Bristol Freighter, this one is CGI I'm pretty sure as there aren't any flying examples to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: That rear 3/4 view reveals this to be one funky lookin' plane! I understand that the design elements make the most of the cargo deck, but still that's a weird looking bird. Also do the loading ramps really extend from the chin without the cargo doors being open? That just adds to the oddness.

Comment: Thank-you. My son suggested it was CGI too. The show is a new TV Series on the ABC (Australian Broadcasting Corporation) "Operation Buffalo" set around the Maralinga Atomic Testing grounds during the 1950's. As Bristol were involved with the Rocket project at Woomera (also in South Aust), I guess there's a nice synergy using a Bristol in this show.

Comment: I'm not sure if the show is geoblocked, ABC have a VOD (ABC iView). If you liked Australian movies "The Dish" or "The Castle" you may enjoy this one.

Answer (score 2):

It was CGI shot at the HARS Museum at Albion Park NSW.  A temporary green screen was built around a C-47. Aircraft VH-AES, VH-AEA and VH-AEF were used, all the internal and external aircraft footage was shot in and around the DC-3 C-47's at the Museum.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. If you have any links or other sources for the claim, [edit]ing them in will improve your answer.